# How to combine two pandas dataframes with a conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dask

There are two pandas dataframes I have which I would like to combine with a rule.

This is the first dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.Dataframe()

df1 

rank    begin    end     labels
first   30953   31131    label1
first   31293   31435    label2
first   31436   31733    label4
first   31734   31754    label1
first   32841   33037    label3
second  33048   33456    label4
....
```

The second dataframe is only two columns, `rank` and `start`

```
df2

rank    start 
first   31333     
first   31434     
first   33039    
first   33123     
first   33125
```

In the first dataframe `df1`, the data has a `begin` and `end`. I would like to check whether the integer for start in `df2` is within this range.

Here is the end result it should look like:

```
result

rank    start     labels
first   31333     label2
first   31434     label2
first   33039     NaN
first   33123     label4
first   33125     label4
```

The `start==31333` is between the range `31293` to `31435` in `df1` with `label = label2`. The integer `31434` is also between the range `31293:31435`, so it also gets annotated with `label2`. The value `33039` is not between any interval in `df2`, so it gets a `NaN` value.

The rule by which these dataframes are combined is this:

```
(df2.start >= df1.begin) & (df2.start <= df1.end)
```

But also, each row must match the same rank value, e.g. each row must match the string first or second for this conditional.

Here is the code I was using to combine these two dataframes, but it doesn't scale very well at all:

```
from numpy import nan

def between_range(row):
    subset = df1.loc[(row["rank"] == df1.rank) & (row.start >= repeats.start) & (row.start <= repeats.end), :]
    if subset.empty:
        return np.nan
    return subset.labels
```

Is there another way to do this with merging (maybe on rank)? Any other pandas-based solution?

Comment: @Kartik I've tried to simplify the question here. Thanks for any help

Comment: @MaxU I've updated the above. Any ideas how this could scale/work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code block

```
def match_labels(row):
    curr_df = df1[ (df1['rank']==row['rank']) & (df1['begin']<=row['start']) & (df1['end']>=row['start']) ]
    try:
        row['labels'] = curr_df['labels'].iloc[0]
    except:
        row['labels'] = np.NaN

    return row

result = df2.apply(lambda x:match_labels(x),axis=1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why would this work when my script above runs for days with nothing to show?

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything quickly with a massive join if you can fit `len(df1)*len(df2)` rows of data into memory:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how = 'left')
df = df.loc[(df.start >= df.begin) & (df.start <= df.end),['rank','start','labels']] # This gives you the correct label of every entry that does indeed belong to a label.
result = df2.merge(df, how = 'left') # This effectively adds the entries that do not belong to any label back into df.
```

This solution also takes care of cases when `start` falls in the range of more than one `begin` and `end` pair: in such cases, you will get as many rows as there are matching labels.

If you can't fit this into memory, you can try partitioning your data by <s>`rank`: do this for just those with `rank == 'first'`, then `rank == 'second'`, and so on.</s> `begin`, `end` and `start`: `df = df2[(df2.start > 31000) & (df2.start <= 32000)].merge(df1[(df1.begin > 31000) & (df1.end <= 32000)], how = 'left')`, for example.

Comment: "If you can't fit this into memory, you can try partitioning your data by rank: do this for just those with rank == 'first', then rank == 'second', and so on." Can you be more specific? Would you try 
`df_rank1 = df.loc[(df.start >= df.begin) & (df.start <= df.end) & (rank=='first',['rank','start','labels']]`
`result_rank1 = df2.merge(df, how = 'left')`

And then concatenate all of these together at the end?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. If you can't see how the code works, try running it with a smaller subset of your data and see what each line does.

Comment: When using smaller subsets, i.e. ` rank == 'first'`, etc., the RAM needed is too large. However, if I were to implement this, how could I use a `for` loop to execute these commands for each "dataframe subsection" and then bring them all together?

Comment: Using smaller subsets by `rank` will not help (by much), as I have corrected myself. You need to subset by factors that avoid joins which you know will be filtered out, which in this case would be by the `begin` and `end` intervals. One way to implement it is to collect every output of the loop into a list of `dfs = [df1,df2,...]` and then use `pd.concat(dfs)`.